# C# Excel Programming - Consistently Reconize Specified Data Type in Range

Tags: c#, excel

I am using the Microsoft Excel classes as part of a program I am writing. I am attempting to add a decimal value (item.Amount) to an Excel cell; however I am receiving the following error:

```
+       $exception  {"Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal'"}  System.Exception {Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException}
```

I understand what is saying, but I do not know how to force the program to view the Excel data as decimal instead of a double.
This line below is giving me trouble:

```
  foreach (SalesItem item in store.salesPLUItems)
        {


         this.sheet.Range[item.colNumber + row].Value2 += item.amount;

            if (item is CreditSales && item.colNumber != "")
            {
                this.sheet.Range[((CreditSales)item).countCol + row].Value += ((CreditSales)item).itemCount;
            }
        }
```

I tried the following addition:

```
    // ensure Excel sees value as decimal
            this.sheet.Range[item.colNumber + row].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(this.sheet.Range[item.colNumber + row].Value);
     this.sheet.Range[item.colNumber + row].Value2 += item.amount;
```

with no success. Neither of the following will even compile

```
 Convert.ToDecimal( this.sheet.Range[item.colNumber + row].Value) += item.amount;
       (this.sheet.Range[item.colNumber + row].Value as Decimal) += item.amount;
```

I tried casting item.amount to a double. However, I still received the error, just at a different row; the roles were just reversed -the value in the Excel range was being viewed as decimal and item.amount as a double.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Tried casting both?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not quite sure what you mean. If you mean casting both the Range.value and item.amount, I am not sure if this would help. item.amount is already a decimal (and the final value really should be a decimal), I just need it to view the Excel cell as a decimal. Or am I misunderstanding? Thanks.

Comment: I meant you should try casting right handside, but when I read my own comment now it seems really ambigous to me too, sorry for that.

What I mean is, did you try casting item.amount to double? 

... += (double)item.amount;

Comment: I was able to fix it by it by just using + instead of += and explicitly casting Range.value on the right side. Not sure if that is exactly what you meant, but either way, your comment definitely pointed me toward the resolution. Thanks!